# Change Blazor JS interop Serializer Settings

Tags: c#, json, blazor, .net-5

I am looking to see how to set the json serializor converter settings when you call `_jsRuntime.InvokeAsync` method. The method it self doesn't take in any json serialization settings. I believe you would need to set the settings for the project. So far I have not been able to find a way to achieve that.

My Converter:

```cs
public class VectorConverter : JsonConverter<System.Numerics.Vector3>
{
    public override System.Numerics.Vector3 Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, 
        Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) 
    {
        if(reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }
        
        System.Numerics.Vector3 result = new System.Numerics.Vector3();
    
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if(reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            {
                return result;
            }
            
            if(reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.PropertyName)                
            {
                throw new JsonException();
            }
            
            switch(reader.GetString())
            {
                case "x":
                    result.X = (float)reader.GetDouble();
                    break;
    
                case "y":
                    result.Y = (float)reader.GetDouble();
                    break;
                
                case "z":
                    result.Z = (float)reader.GetDouble();
                    break;
            }
        }
    
        throw new JsonException();
    }
    
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, 
        System.Numerics.Vector3 value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {    
        writer.WriteNumber("x", value.X);
        writer.WriteNumber("y", value.Y);
        writer.WriteNumber("z", value.Z);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens without a converter?  Because JS doesn't know about Vector3.

Comment: OK, never mind. Vector3 is a mutable struct with public fields, no properties.

Comment: @HenkHolterman the converter isn't invoked because I cannot find a way to add it to the json serializor. The Json serialization between C# and JS happens implicitly.

Comment: Don't try to serialize System.Numerics.Vector3 to begin with. JS interop uses specific serialization protocols that must be know both when serializing and *de*serializing on the JS side. It keeps changing to improve performance and when possible, interop will *avoid* JS serialization. Besides, Vector3 is meant for high-performance SIMD-accelerated operations that simply don't exist in WASM.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to transfer a large number of data to a JS function you could use stream or byte-array interop, whose performance improved by *removing* encoding. Check [Stream from .NET to JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0#stream-from-net-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

As of writing, it seems it is unfortunately not possible (and STILL not possible) to modify the JSON serializer configuration in a Blazor app. The `JsonSerializerOptions` instance configured for the `JSRuntime` abstract base class is internal, and getter-only. So no way for us to modify the `Converters` collection. It's not even virtual, so you won't be able to subclass `JSRuntime` itself.

[Relevant source here.](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/442a380854c25b85252a743c3ba2e21f08fa6879/src/JSInterop/Microsoft.JSInterop/src/JSRuntime.cs#L31)

Also worth mentioning it's not using the static `Default` instance either, which is by the way also not possible to be configured because in the app's entry point it seems it's already been used (and there is a check in place to not modify it once used). It wouldn't matter much though, as `JSRuntime` doesn't use this.

Comment: And will probably never become possible. JS interop marshalling isn't general purpose serialization. The JavaScript side needs to know how to handle the data it receives, something that would break if custom converters were allowed. Encoding or worse, serialization are slow, so JS interop tries to avoid them when possible. A major change in [byte-array and stream interopo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/6.0/byte-array-interop) was to remove the need for encoding